# How to Host Locally MaxMind Database for Sitecore8

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, maxmind

I want to use the geoip functionality of Sitecore8 by locally hosting maxmind database. I've install the Sitecore IP Geolocation Service Client 1.2 rev. 150602 module in my Sitecore Instance and planning to locally host maxmind database for testing purposes. Are there any steps on what should I configure? for both Sitecore and Maxmind. I just referenced in a post [here](https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/p/415/6631#6631) Thank you in advance.

Comment: The locally hosted MaxMind has as purpose to use the free lite version. with less data fields. you can found it on the marketplace https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/G/GeoLite_Lookup_Provider.aspx

Comment: Great, Im going to try this and reply with the feedback. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried installing the module but still it doesn't work. The module is currently outdated. Any more approaches other than this? Thanks

Comment: The code is include on the marketplace you can adapt it. And recent @craig-taylor put it on GitHub https://github.com/craigtfromatl/Sitecore-GeoLite-Lookup-Provider maybe he has plans?

Comment: Check out this [link](https://sitecorecontextitem.wordpress.com/2014/07/09/a-list-of-custom-sitecore-dms-functionality/), I'm thinking this is what I need to do but I don't know how to implement it.